# -fno-diagnostcs-color Doesn't remove formatting

Tags: gcc, console, syntax-highlighting

Here's a sample output from `make`:

```
gcc -fno-diagnostics-color -Wall -fPIC -ggdb -I. -c parens.c -o parens.o
In file included from parens.y:4:0:
parens.h:10:22: error: expected identifier before â\200\230(â\200\231 token
 #define GREATER_THAN (1 << 6)
```

Notice the `â\200\230(â\200\231` part.

GCC version: `gcc (Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) 6.3.0 20170406`.

`$GCC_COLORS` is not defined.

How to get rid of the extra formatting, which isn't printed correctly anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These non-ASCII characters are not formatting, but UTF-8-encoded quotation marks.  Try setting the `LC_ALL` environment variable to `C` (or perhaps just `LC_CTYPE`), then GCC will emit ASCII quotation marks instead.

Alternatively, tell you terminal to handle UTF-8 properly, which is probably the better investment because UTF-8 is supposed to be ubiquitous these days.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Though I'd also like, if possible, to remove Unicode characters from GCC output too. I really don't need that. For future reference, this was a configuration issue in Emacs, which was solved in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668580/how-to-get-support-for-%E2%9C%96-and-the-like-in-the-emacs-shell-buffer